# Automatically append parameters to *_url or *_path methods (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, path

I have a particular set of views relating to one of my controllers, whereby I want any call to `*_path` or `*_url` to append a set of parameters.

Is there some magic method I can override that will let me do this?  I have no idea where in the Rails code the `*_path` or `*_url` methods are even handled.

**Edit for clarity:** I'm looking for a way to do this such that I don't have to modify every link in every view where this needs to occur.  I don't want every coder who touches this set of views to have to remember to append a parameter to every link they add to the page.  The same parameter should be appended automatically.  I consider a change to the `*_url` or `*_path` call a failure.  Similarly, having to override every `*_url` or `*_path` call is considered a failure since a new method would have to be added/removed whenever a new link is added/removed.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: On Facebook canvas pages, all "fb_*" params must be appended to all links appearing in the app such that Facebook data pertaining to the logged in user can be accessed via their API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Samuel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216906/automatically-append-parameters-to-url-or-path-methods-rails/4221791#4221791), I was able to create a final working solution via a new helper, which I've included below.

```
module ExampleHelper
  def url_for(options={})
    options = case options
    when String
      uri = Addressable::URI.new
      uri.query_values = @hash_of_additional_params

      options + (options.index('?').nil? ? '?' : '&') + uri.query
    when Hash
      options.reverse_merge(@hash_of_additional_params)
    else
      options
    end

    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that it requires you to use `gem 'addressable'`

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by overriding `url_for` since all the routing methods call it.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def url_for(options = {})
    options.reverse_merge!(@extra_url_for_options) if @extra_url_for_options
    super
  end
end
```

Now all you need to do is use a `before_filter` to set `@extra_url_for_options` to a hash to force all urls.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter do { @extra_url_for_options = { :format => 'html' } }
end
```

Note that this will force *all* links to use the extra options.

Comment: Ahh, this is what I was looking for.  I knew there had to be a magic method somewhere, but I didn't know what it was.  I assume I can do the same with a ControllerSpecificHelper instead of ApplicationHelper, correct?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `options` is not a hash, but a string when I call `*_path` or `*_url`, which means I can't call `reverse_merge!` on it. I supposed I could just append the parameters to that string and call super that way, does that seem right?

Comment: Thanks for the help, you lead me to a proper solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216906/automatically-append-parameters-to-url-or-path-methods-rails/4228338#4228338

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the [with_options](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options) method. In your view you can do something like

```
<% with_options :my_param => "my_value" do |append| -%>

  <%= append.users_path(1) %>

<% end %>
```

Assuming you have the users_path of course. **my_param=value** will be appended to the url

Answer (score 0):

You could make a helper method:

```
def my_path(p)
  "#{p}_path all the parameters I want to append"
end
```

and in the view use

```
<%= eval(my_path(whatever)) %>
```

Eval with give you dynamic scope, so every variable available in your view can be used in the helper.  If your parameters are constant you can get rid of eval calls.

Comment: But then I'll have to write about 20 methods, one for each in the page, and manually update the helper each time a new URL is referenced. I'm looking for something I can do it one place and have it affect every `*_url`/`*_path` call on the page.

Comment: You just use eval(my_path('whatever')) instead of whatever_path everywhere - the helper takes a parameter to path name, no need to write more than one method.  If I didn't understand you right then please explain.

Comment: I guess I fail to see how `eval(my_path(whatever))` is better than `my_path(whatever, extra_whatever)`...  I'm looking for a way to not have to edit every link in every view, such that if someone else comes along and adds a link to the view in our code base, they don't need to remember to wrap it in an `eval()`, append the extra parameters manually, or do anything else special.

Comment: extra_whatever is probably a big hash, eval(my_path(whatever)) doesn't require copying any code - if you'd want to update the parameters, you'd need to do it only in one place.

Comment: Even if `extra_whatever` is a hash, I only need to update it in one place still...the place where `extra_whatever` is defined.

Comment: That would require defining extra_whatever in the view which is quite bad (well eval is quite bad too).  Anyway the other answer seems to be a quite cool way to solve this.

Comment: Not true, I currently define `@extra_whatever` in the controller. I posted this question in hopes of a better solution. :)

Comment: If you'd use a partial you'd have to pass @extra_whatever as a local to every partial.  Thinking of it with_options wouldn't work then too, without extra tweaking, but if you don't use partials in your view it should be sufficient.