# Rails 3 Attaching Model ID to every link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My application centers around an event and specifically the event's ID. Whenever a user navigates to different sections (controllers) of the site, I need to be able to carry the event's ID with it.

I'm guessing including the event's ID in the URL is the preferred method in case a user opens multiple browser windows.

I don't want to manually append the event's ID to every link. Is there a helper method I could create to do this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a nested resource in your routes file, this will add something like "/event/#eventid" to the beginning of your path. You can then access this from your controllers with `params[:event_id]`

eg:

routes.rb

```
resources :events do
  # Other controllers routes go here
end
```

controller_whatever.rb

```
def index
  @whatever = Event.find(params[:event_id]).whatever.all
end

...
```

Obviously it would be best to use a before filter, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should store that in session data:

```
session[:event_id] = event_id
```

You will then be able to access that throughout the user's session.

**UPDATE**:

You may want to have a look at [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Since a user can manage multiple events, I'm afraid they'll try to open up 2 tabs within the browser to edit 2 different events. If I use a session variable then that will mess up the data integrity between the 2 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use thomasfedb's solution. If it isn't possible for any reason you could do it by overwriting the url_for method like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216906/automatically-append-parameters-to-url-or-path-methods-rails)